# I want to print letters(strings) with odd or even numbers as their index and save them as a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, range

I want to print and save letters of this word "**complexity**"; I want to iterate through the word and get every letter that has an **even number as its index**, store or save it in a list, and also get every letter that has an **odd number as its index** and save it as a list in their respective variables. Below is the code.

```
word = "complexity"
even_letters = ""
odd_letters = ""
for index in range(0,len(word)):

    if int(index) % 2 == 0:
       even_letters = word[index]
   else:
        odd_letters = word[index]

print(list(even_letters))
print(list(odd_letters))
```

But my results shows only this:

> ['t']
>
> ['y']

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting the strings instead of adding to them.

Change

```
even_letters = word[index]
```

To

```
even_letters += word[index]
```

`=` reassigns (overwrites). `+=` appends (add to).

Comment: well I just did that and am getting "TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'"

Comment: @SamJereriaManuel I just tried it, it works fine. You must have a space after the `+` or something.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you said, you want to save the different letters as a list then you even_letters and odd_letters must be initialized as lists and you must append the letters, not reseting their value.
If I were you I would also use the enumerate option in python so you can get the index and the letter at the same time.

```
word = "complexity"
even_letters = []
odd_letters = []
for index, letter in enumerate(word):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        even_letters.append(letter)
    else:
        odd_letters.append(letter)
print(list(even_letters))

print(list(odd_letters))
```

If you want to obtain a string instead of a list, then you can change 
    even_letters = letter
and
    odd_letters = letter
for 
    even_letters += letter
    odd_letters += letter

Answer (score 1):

This can be done more easily with list comprehensions:

```
even_letters = [c for i, c in enumerate(word) if i % 2 == 0]
odd_letters = [c for i, c in enumerate(word) if i % 2 == 1]
```